# Command execution in tcl shell when python is called from the TCL shell

Tags: python-2.7, tcl

I'm writing a GUI utility using tkinter and I'm calling the python script from a TCL shell of a unix software. Now, I'm able to create the GUI as I want, but unable to execute any commands in the main TCL shell through the GUI. Is there any way we can realize it? **Basically, I want to execute certain commands in the main TCL shell(from which python script was called), using the GUI created using Tkinter**.

PS: I know the client-socket way to establish communication, wherein I write a socket.py and client.tcl, but the problem is that I need to keep on coming to the TCL shell to execute the client TCL which defeats the purpose of having a tkinter based GUI.

Comment: I'm not understanding your architecture. You have tclsh -> python -> tkinter. What's the purpose of the python layer instead of just tcl & tk (with a single tcl interpreter)? Nevertheless, put the code that needs to live in both tclsh and tkinter into a library file, and both Tcl interpreters can `source` it.

Comment: Actually, this requirement was not there initially. So I wrote things in Python and I have come some way into this. Currently, I'm trying to avoid restarting my work in TCL/Tk again, hence exploring this option.

Comment: Is there a purpose to the initial tclsh layer? This question has the smell of needless complexity.

Comment: Yes. The 1st TCL shell interface is part of the software from which this script needs to be executed. 
Basically, the commands I'm looking to execute from Tkinter GUI are software-specific commands(may not be purely TCL)., This is possible only if Python script can execute something back in the original TCL shell from where it was invoked.

Comment: It really does sound like it'd be better to rewrite the GUI part in tcl/tk running in the original tcl script instead of messing with IPC between tcl and python.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve]. Your description of the problem isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you would run:

```
catch { exec ifconfig } result
puts $result
```

For example, this would give you the result as output from the command 'ifconfig', which is a *nix os dependent command.